# Match everything till the last exact string in the exact div (php)

Tags: php, html, regex

I want to match the address of a property on realty server. Lets say the div containing address is named `<div class="title">` and the address is located in the last `<h2>` section like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="price">
    <h2>
      h2
    </h2>
  </div>      
  <div class="title">
    <abcd>
      abcd
    </abcd>
    <efg>
      efg
    </efg>
    <h2>
      adress
    </h2>
 </div>
</body>
```

Is there a possible way to capture an address by only one regex, even if it will be in some captured group?

My not working solution is:

```
regex="/<div class="title">everything_except_<h2>*([^<]*)/";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
<div class="title">(?:.(?!<\/div>))*<h2>([^<]*)
```

The main point here is to make `.*` after `<div class="title">` greedy but match only until `</div>` is found. So the regex limits the `.` with only those occurrences that are not followed by `</div>` (which gives us `(?:.(?!<\/div>))*` as a result).

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/2EGXue/1

**Update:**

If nested `div`s may occur but only one level of nesting is possible and the required `<h2>...</h2>` is not within any of those `div`s (as it happens in the provided data sample), the greedily matching pattern (`.(?!<\/div>)`) should be extended to match either "not `<div ...>...</div>`" (which is `<div.*?<\/div>`) or just "not `</div>`" (`.(?!<\/div>)`):

```
<div class="title">(?:<div.*?<\/div>|.(?!<\/div>))*<h2>([^<]*)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/IGLhBZ/1

Comment: well it is not working for the original site, have a look: http://pastebin.com/7JF1uQvZ

Comment: @nocturne Note the `s` modifier as well.

Comment: @nocturne: this is because of nested `div`s. This is a substantial condition and the regex requires some adjustment to take it into account.

Comment: can you tell my why is this not working? `/<div class="title">(?:.(?!<h2>))*([^<]*)/` capture everything till the h2 and the capture adress

Comment: @nocturne: because it stops on the first closing `</div>` for a nested `div`. Please see the updated answer with nested `div`'s supported.